# UPDATE specific fields in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I've a table in MySQL named `product` where fields are set as below..

```
id int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
nm varchar(255),
category varchar(255),
price int(4)
```

when i insert a new product then I've put some code to check duplication as below.

```
select nm,category from product where nm='".$pnm."' AND category='".$cat."'
```

If there is any row then code will not insert that record in database...(problem starts now)
same condition I've set during update..
if user edit that product and change name or category which is already in database then it'll return false and exit the code..

now if i want to just update price then name and category will be same then what to do???

please give your best ! ! 
Thank you friends

Comment: Well, you just update the column price in that case. You do not do your clause that prevents doing so, since it does not make sense in this case. Please post your `update` query.

Comment: for update check `select nm,category from product where nm='".$pnm."' AND category='".$cat."' AND id !='update record id'`

Comment: UPDATE product SET price = '".$price."' WHERE nm='".$pnm."' AND category='".$cat."' ?

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid you're answer is working..

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using unique id..First check for duplication while updating and if duplication occurs then only update other fields except name and category else update all the fields which are going to be changed.

I give you demo.Make changes according to your requirement like field name,table name and all that.

```
$sql="select * from product where nm='".$_REQUEST['name']."'" or category='".$_REQUEST['category']."';
$query=mysql_query($sql);
if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0)
{
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
 {
   $id=$row['id'];
   if(isset($_REQUEST['price']))
   {
    $sql="update product set price='".$_REQUEST['price']."' where id='$id'";
    $query=mysql_query($sql);
   }
 }
}
else
{
$sql="update product set nm='".$_REQUEST['name']."',category='".$_REQUEST['category']."',price='".$_REQUEST['price']."' where id='$id'";
$query=mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two step solution: 
- Create a UNIQUE index 
- Use `INSERT IGNORE` and `UPDATE IGNORE` instead of `INSERT` and `UPDATE`